# How does one go about suggesting a tag synonym be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Upvote, downvote, I don't care. I really would like to see [sqllite](/questions/tagged/sqllite) removed as a synonym for [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite). Yes, SQLite is a little tricky, but sqllite is not a legitimate name for the product. By the way, I am asking this as someone with under 2500 reputation.

Comment: I don't think that "Upvote, downvote, I don't care" is a good introduction to your question. If you don't care, no need to claim it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you think that a synonym tag should not be used, then you can post here.

I think you misunderstood the purpose of synonym tags.
When a tag is set as synonym of another tag, the first tag is replaced by the second tag in all the questions where the tag is used. In your case, if you use [sqllite](/questions/tagged/sqllite) in a question, when you save the question you are asking, you will notice that the question is being tagged [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite).
In this case, the tag has been probably created because enough users kept to misspell the tag as [sqllite](/questions/tagged/sqllite). The problem is with users who can create new tags, and who would create a new separate tag all times they misspell [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite), if [sqllite](/questions/tagged/sqllite) were not a synonym tag.

Setting a synonym tag doesn't mean to consider it correct; quite the opposite, it means to mark the synonym tag as less preferable or not correct.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks, I think I confused myself because I am too tired.  Now if we can only have a similar feature that works on the body and the title.  Both answers great, but you win by 3 minutes.

Answer (score 8):

That's actually why it's a synonym.
One of the purposes of synonyms is so that misspelled variations will bring up the correctly spelled tag.